# Cannot add views to ComposeView; only Compose content is supported

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm attempting to add Jetpack Compose composables to my xml file in a fragment.

When I try to run it on a device I'm getting an error:
`Cannot add views to ComposeView; only Compose content is supported`

### Fragment:

```
class ComposeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, container, false
        )
        view.findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black))
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {

                Text("THIS IS A COMPOSABLE INSIDE THE FRAGMENT XML")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                CircularProgressIndicator()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                Text("NEAT")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

            }
        }

        return view
    }

}
```

### activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        />

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.kt:

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.compose_view, ComposeFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what this error means or how to address it.  I can't find this error anywhere by googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MainActivity you are trying to put a fragment inside a ComposeView (which takes only Composable).

> You should specify the right container for your Fragment:
>
> ```
> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
>         .replace(R.id.main_container, ComposeFragment())
>         .commit()
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`replace(R.id.compose_view, ComposeFragment())` is adding a Fragment to your `ComposeView`, not to your `FragmentContainerView` - that's what is adding a `View` to your `ComposeView`.

If you want to add a Fragment to your `FragmentContainerView`, you'll need to use the  ID of the `FragmentContainerView`:

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Always surround any FragmentTransactions in a
        // savedInstanceState == null since fragment are
        // automatically restored and you don't want to replace
        // those restored fragments
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, ComposeFragment())
                .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

It isn't clear why your Activity is inflating `activity_main` and your Fragment is also inflating `activity_main` - those should be different layouts and you should choose if you want your activity's layout to only host a fragment (thereby removing the `ComposeView` from its layout) and have the fragment contain your `ComposeView` or if you want to skip the fragment entirely and directly have your `ComposeView` in your Activity. Doing both (in particular, in your layout where they would overlap one another due to your use of `RelativeLayout`) doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Ok. I think I was fundamentally misunderstanding how these things work.  I didn't appreciate that the three of these sort of work all together and wherever you place the fragment container is where the view ends up.  Thank you for the comments!